# SQLでカラム値の意味が動的に変わる場合の絞り込み方法について

Tags: sql, oracle

以下のようなテーブル構成でRESULT_NAMEのNAME1~3のいずれかが'TEST1'であり、
TEST1に対応したRESULT_VALUE.VALUE1～3のいずれかを取得するSQLを実装することは可能でしょうか？
DBMSはOracle 19cを想定しています。

なお、RESULT_VALUEとRESULT_NAMEの結合キーはIDカラムになります。

1.RESULT_VALUEテーブル

```
+-----------+----+
|  Column   | PK |
+-----------+----+
| ID        |  1 |
| DETAIL_ID |  2 |
| VALUE1    |    |
| VALUE2    |    |
| VALUE3    |    |
+-----------+----+
```

2.RESULT_NAMEテーブル

```
+--------+----+
| Column | PK |
+--------+----+
| ID     |  1 |
| NAME1  |    |
| NAME2  |    |
| NAME3  |    |
+--------+----+
```

・RESULT_VALUEの値例

```
+----+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | DETAIL_ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
+----+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |        01 | V01    | V02    | V03    |
|  1 |        02 | V11    | V12    | V13    |
|  1 |        03 | V21    | V22    | V33    |
+----+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

・RESULT_NAMEの値例

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | NAME1 | NAME2 | NAME3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | TEST1 | TEST2 | TEST3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

インデックスも効かずスマートな方法ではありませんが、`decode`か`case`を使うSQLで手っ取り早く実装することが可能です。

```
-- 疑似テーブル定義
with RESULT_VALUE as
    (select 1 ID, '01' DETAIL_ID, 'V01' VALUE1, 'V02' VALUE2, 'V03' VALUE3 from dual union all
     select 1 ID, '02' DETAIL_ID, 'V11' VALUE1, 'V12' VALUE2, 'V13' VALUE3 from dual union all
     select 1 ID, '03' DETAIL_ID, 'V21' VALUE1, 'V22' VALUE2, 'V23' VALUE3 from dual),
     RESULT_NAME as
    (select 1 ID, 'TEST1' NAME1, 'TEST2' NAME2, 'TEST3' NAME3 from dual)
-- サンプルSQL
select V.ID,
       V.DETAIL_ID,
       -- NAMExが 'TEST1' に該当する時、対応するVALUExを取得する
       decode('TEST1',
              N.NAME1, V.VALUE1,
              N.NAME2, V.VALUE2,
              N.NAME3, V.VALUE3,
              null)
from   RESULT_NAME N, RESULT_VALUE V
where  N.ID = V.ID
```